# Is there a way to call a VBS fuction inside Post processor Beanshell - Jmeter

Tags: vbscript, jmeter

Hi I've a piece of code in VBS file and a function is associated with that

code. I want to call that vbscript function inside a beanshell after Jmeter

execute all its sampler .Is there a way to call a vbs function inside a

beanshell?  Please suggest...

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript c:/jmeter/bin/yourscript.vbs);
```

See [Runtime class JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-) for more details on the approach.

However if your script produces some console output it might be easier to use [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) configured like:

[image: JMeter OS Process Sampler]

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article to learn how to execute 3rd-party applications from JMeter tests.

Comment: Hi I have vb function which holds one parameter for ex:-Function Sub(X) and i want to call that Sub(6) function inside my jmeter scripts where i want to pass the parameter (Here in our case 6) from Jmeter. How to call that function and how to pass that parameter from Jmeter.please suggest..